# How to trigger cursor fuse on specific entities only

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I have my camera and cursor set up this way:

```
    <a-camera>
      <a-cursor 
        fuse="true"
        animation__fusing="property: scale; startEvents: fusing; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 1500; from: 1 1 1; to: 0.1 0.1 0.1"
        animation__mouseleave="property: scale; startEvents: mouseleave; easing: easeInCubic; dur: 500; to: 1 1 1">
      </a-cursor>
    </a-camera>
```

And a scene looking like this:

```
    <a-entity id="scene1">
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" onclick="changeLevel('scene1', 'scene2')"></a-box>
      <a-sky src="background1.png"></a-sky>
    </a-entity>
```

Now the cursor is always fusing, even when looking at the skybox. Is it possible to start the fusing animation only when looking at clickable entities?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the cursor through the [raycaster component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html#configuring-the-cursor-through-the-raycaster-component). In your case:

```
  <a-cursor fuse="true" raycaster="objects: a-box" ....
```

You can set a class for your interactive objects, to make it clear:

```
  <a-box class="clickable"></a-box>
  ...
  <a-cursor raycaster="objects: .clickable" ...
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2uhm8yzw/1/).

Comment: Btw, consider throwing any logic into a [a-frame component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/component.html#sidebar).

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! I just added the property objects=".clickable" on my a-cursor, and class="clickable" on the a-box, and it worked!